# Как добавить в массив все данные введенные пользователем?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста, как добавить все данные введенные пользователем в массив. у меня получается что добавляется только последние введенные данные.

```
let arr = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    var command = prompt('Введите команду');
    var arrays = command.split(' ');
}
var index = arrays[0];
var name = arrays[1];


if (index == 'add') {
    arr.push(name);

}

console.log(arr);
```

если ввести add Tom, потом add John например добавляется последние данные. а надо чтобы и первый тоже добавился.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо условия переместить в цикл.

```js
let arr = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    var command = prompt('Введите команду');
    var arrays = command.split(' ');
    
    var index = arrays[0];
    var name = arrays[1];

    if (index == 'add') {
        arr.push(name);
    }
}

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: О, спасибо большое. А я так же внутри цикла могу использовать оператор switch case?

Comment: Никто не запрещал пока

Comment: а еще один вопрос. 

switch (index) {
        case 'add':
            arr.push(name);
           
        case 'delete':
            arr.splice(name);
            console.log(arr);
    }

почему если я добавляю case 'delete': arr.splice(name); , то данные в массив не добавляются

Comment: Если есть ещё один вопрос, то вам сюда: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask